# PHP: Split a string in to an array foreach char

Tags: php, arrays, split, passwords, validation

I am making a method so your password needs at least one captial and one symbol or number.
I was thinking of splitting the string in to lose chars and then use preggmatch to count if it contains one capital and symbol/number.

however i did something like this in action script but can't figure out how this is called in php. i cant find a way to put every char of a word in a array.

AS3 example

```
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < thisWordCode.length -1 ; i++)
{
    thisWordCodeVerdeeld[i] = thisWordCode.charAt(i);
    //trace (thisWordCodeVerdeeld[i]);
}
```

Thanks,
Matthy

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can access characters in strings in the same way as you would access an array index, e.g.

```
$length = strlen($string);
$thisWordCodeVerdeeld = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    $thisWordCodeVerdeeld[$i] = $string[$i];
}
```

You could also do:

```
$thisWordCodeVerdeeld = str_split($string);
```

However you might find it is easier to validate the string as a whole string, e.g. using regular expressions.

Comment: Documentation for square bracket notation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: use isset instead of strlen:     `for ($i=0; isset($string[$i]); $i++) {`

Comment: $thisWordCodeVerdeeld = str_split($string);

This is perfect answer for separating string characters and getting each of them in an array.

Answer (score 98):

you can convert a string to array with [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and use foreach

```
$chars = str_split($str);
foreach($chars as $char){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is the nicest way.  It might not be the fastest, but for most applications it doesn't matter, at all. In our app, the speed difference was not even possible to measure. (Vs for-loop.)

Comment: Also agree that this is the better answer, since it's the more directly answering the question

Comment: Note that if `$str` is an empty string `str_split` will return `[""]`

Comment: This is still the nicest answer. Only that it is now best to use `mb_str_split` to handle multibyte strings correctly.

Answer (score 16):

You can access a string using `[]`, as you do for arrays:

```
$stringLength = strlen($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $stringLength; $i++)
    $char = $str[$i];
```

Comment: this doesn't work correctly for multibyte string like: 'éléphant'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666306/how-to-iterate-utf-8-string-in-php

Answer (score 16):

Since `str_split()` function is not multibyte safe, an easy solution to split UTF-8 encoded string is to use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with [`u (PCRE_UTF8)`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier.

```
preg_split( '//u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It works beter for UTF8 characters (Kurdish, Persian and Arabic):

```
<?php
$searchTerm = "هێڵەگ";
$chars = preg_split("//u", $searchTerm, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
foreach($chars as $char){echo $char."<br>";}
?>
```

Comment: `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`? You aren't using any capture groups!