# There are simple way to get a character from multibyte string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, encoding, multibyte

This is my problem: My language (Portuguese) uses ISO-8859-1 char encoding! When I want access a character from a string like 'coração' (heart) I use:

```
mb_internal_encoding('ISO-8859-1');
$str = "coração";

$len = mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8');

for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i)
    echo mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')."<br/>";
```

This produces:

```
c
o
r
a
ç
ã
o
```

This works fine... But my issue is if the use of mb_substr function is not fast as simple string normal access! But I want a simple way to do this.... like in normal string character access: echo $str[$pos].... It is possible?

Answer (score 4):

> mb_substr function is not fast as [...] like in normal string character access: echo $str[$pos].... It is possible?

No.

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

The multibyte functions have to check every character to determine how many bytes (1 to 4 in UTF-8) it occupies. There you immediately have the reason why character indexing (`$a[n]`) won't work: you don't know what byte(s) you need to get the *n* th character before you've read all characters before that one.

To speed things up a bit, you can look at the answers here: [How to iterate UTF-8 string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666306/how-to-iterate-utf-8-string-in-php)

However, since you use ISO 8859-1 or Latin-1, you don't have to use the `mb_` functions at all, since in that encoding all characters are [encoded in one byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: Upvoted.  Essentially the two answers on the link provided, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14366023/793036) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17156392/793036) if you have mbstring.func_overload set to 7, are what you want.  They basically do the indexing if it's available and use the slow mb_substr only if necessary.  In OP's example, it will only require mb_substr once.

Comment: Thank you for the usefull links and explainations provided. 5 years later, still the most relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
preg_match_all( "/./u", $str, $ar_chars );
print_r( $ar_chars );
```

Answer (score 0):

... Sort of. If you use a fixed-width encoding (ISO 8859-*, UCS-2, or UTF-32, or UTF-16 within the BMP) then you can use a fixed multiplier for character accesses. You will still need to make multiple accesses for the multiple-byte encodings though.

Comment: Well... But my question is about a efficient way to do these accesses. I tested a normal string concatenation loop ($new_str .= $old_str[2] - just for testing...) and using mb_substr ($new_str .= mb_substr($old_str, 2, 1, 'UTF-8') and I got this (with loop 50 000 iterations): 0.016 s to normal access against 4.9802091121674 s to mb_substr function! It's a big performance trouble!

Comment: With a fixed-width encoding you can use a fixed multiplier.

Comment: How I could do this then? Show me an example!

Comment: `substr($ucs2string, $pos * 2, 2)`

Comment: Well... but and about performance issue (like i showed in the test I realized [above])?