# PHP: Get encoded html entities

Tags: php, html-entities

I'm trying to get the html entities of a UTF-8 string,
**Example:** `example.com/search?q=مرحبا`

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities($_GET['q']);
?>
```

**I got:**

```
Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§0Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§
```

It's UTF-8 text not html entities,
**what I need is:**

```
&#1605;&#1585;&#1581;&#1576;&#1575;
```

I have tried `urldecode` and `htmlentities` functions!

Comment: @AbraCadaver pardon!

Comment: You need to change the Html page Encoding to unicode UTF-8, you can check the current encoding from the browser. To change the default encoding see @user1122069 answer.

Comment: @Coder please select your answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the start of your file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

The browser needs to know it is UTF-8. This tag also can go in the head section for formality.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it by getting the each char in the string and get its value.
From [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)'s **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9361531)** and [vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60711/vartec)'s **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3666326)** you can get:

```
<?php
    $chrArray = preg_split('//u',$_GET['q'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $htmlEntities = "";
    foreach ($chrArray as $chr) {
        $htmlEntities .= '&#'._uniord($chr).';';
    }
    echo $htmlEntities;
?>
```

**I have not test it.**