# Why $string[3] is not the same as 3nd char in $string?

Tags: php

I have example string in UTF-8:

```
$string = "Nový rok";
```

Now i tried:

```
echo $string; // output: Nový rok // CORRECT
echo $string[0] // output: N // CORRECT
echo $string[3] // output: � // INCORRECT
```

Why `$string[3]` is incorrect?

I also tried convert string to array by `str_split` but results is same. Here is code of my test:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
    $string = str_split("Nový rok");
    echo $string[3];
?>
```

Any idea how to get "ý" from array?

Comment: Because multi-byte character. Notes statements on the documentation page `str_split() will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.`

Comment: Possibly becuase UTF8 does not use 1 byte per char so split them using this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666306/how-to-iterate-utf-8-string-in-php

Comment: @markdwhite thanks for link

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)